# How to create HTML fieldset and legend in asp.net code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

How to create HTML fieldset and legend in asp.net code behind? and add controls in that fieldset?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this:

```
<asp:Panel ID="myPanel" runat="server" GroupingText="My Fieldset Title" />
```

[Check this as well](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel.groupingtext.aspx)

Comment: This does have the drawback of placing the fieldset inside a div, which might not be what you need. If it's not an issue, then this is perfect.

Comment: I agree, asp will do what it wants with the html, and not use the existing html tags :(

Comment: Obviously, The code behind would be like this:
    Panel panel = new Panel() { GroupingText = "My Fieldset Title" };
    panel.Controls.Add(myControl);