# how to create a fieldset with legend using ASP.NET CLR language VB or C#?

Tags: asp.net, clr, fieldset

How to create, programmatically, using C# or VB.NET, a fieldset with a legend and some content, so that the resulting generated markup would look like this?

```
     <fieldset><legend>foo</legend>res ipsa loquitur</fieldset>
```

Not looking for alternatives to `<fieldset>` as suggested here:

[How to create HTML fieldset and legend in asp.net code behind?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655571/how-to-create-html-fieldset-and-legend-in-asp-net-code-behind)

Can this be done with ASP.NET *HtmlGenericControl*?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, this can be done with an HtmlGeneric control.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: I was trying to add the legend as an attribute to the generic control.

Comment: you should also upvote the answer that best addresses your needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Literal l = new Literal();
l.Mode = LiteralMode.PassThrough;
l.Text = "<fieldset><legend>foo</legend>res ipsa loquitur</fieldset>";
this.Controls.Add(l);
```

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping to be able to do it without building the literal string and starting/ending tags, but I'll accept this as an answer.